# problems running angularjs e2e testing with protractor in phantomjs

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor

When doing E2E tests with Protractor and PhantomJS and doing things like

```
expect(element(by.repeater('book in library') row(0).column('{{book.name}}')).getText()).toBe('Some Text');
```

fails only in PhantomJS, but not in Firefox or Chrome.

Html

```
<div>
  <ui tabset> 
    <li tab ng-repeat="book in library track by id"> 
      <span tab-heading>{{book.name}}</span>      
      <div ui-view="test"></div>
    </li>
  </ui>
</div>
```

Protractor E2E test case:

```
 it('test', function () {
  var bookName = element(by.repeater('book in library track by id').row(0).column('{{book.name}}'));
  expect(bookName.getText()).toEqual('test');
 });
```

I am using angularjs 1.2.14, protractor:1.0.0-rc4, phantomjs:1.9.7-14 on linux
This test case runs well in Chrome and Firefox but fails in PhantomJS and the error I get is

```
 Error:Expected '' to equal 'test'
```

When I do count on rows works fine but trying to fetch column value, I am getting the empty string.

```
// works fine:
expect(element.all(by.repeater('book in library track by id')).count()).toEqual(9); 
// test fails:
expect(bookName.getText()).toEqual('test');
```

Is there way to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a phantomjs related issue so? You should [submit it](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues) with the label `phantomjs problem` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's a WebDriver known behavior. The `WebDriver` returns an empty String when the `getText()` method is called on a non-visible element. And, sometimes, even is the element is visible, it still returns an empty String.

I've found several solutions in [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888592/gettext-method-of-selenium-chrome-driver-sometimes-returns-an-empty-string), but none worked for me (Selenium, PhantomJS, and a ZK application). The `innerText` attribute was empty too.

I found my solution [here](http://yizeng.me/2014/04/08/get-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-webdriver/). The trick was to use the `textContent` attribute, which returned the expected value when the `getText()` returned an empty String.

```
WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='myDiv']"));
assertEquals("expectedtext", div.getAttribute("textContent"));
```