# How to store a value in a variable in Katalon Recorder?

Tags: katalon-recorder

I'm trying to store the verification code into verfcode variable. How can I do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to store a text from the table cell - you could just use

> storeTable(tableCellAddress, variableName)

Anyway, you can always use storeText, but it all depends on from where the text is supposed to be stored.

If you would like to know about why getText gets empty string, you should probably read this answer - [getText() method of selenium chrome driver sometimes returns an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888592/gettext-method-of-selenium-chrome-driver-sometimes-returns-an-empty-string)